# How to fix Power Query Multiple Workbooks Header Appears as Rows?

Tags: powerquery

[Picture Here Please](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvK4T.png)
Please look, each worksheet header appears as row.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is pretty vague, but if you need your first row of data to be the header then click on the small icon of a table in the upper left-hand of the table and select "Use First Rows as Headers". I have attached a photo to help. [image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Look I have multiple workbooks, when I combine them, the headers of each workbook appears in between as row. There should be common header for all. Even the headers are same.

Comment: Did you check the picture I have attached?

Comment: Filter out the common header to remove the inbetween rows

Comment: After promoting the header, filter out "Name" by clicking on the drop-down button next to "Column1" and unchecking "Name". This should remove all of the duplicate rows. You can also filter out the rows within the function. For example
'...each ([Column 1]) <> "Name"'

Answer (score 1):

You can promote the headers in the nested tables, then expand the tables using the 'correct' column names.

Currently in your #"Expanded Custom" step, you have a Data column, which is a nested table like the below
[image]

If you insert a new step after the #"Expanded Custom" step and add the following;

```
= Table.TransformColumns(#"Expanded Custom", {"Data", each Table.PromoteHeaders(_)})
```

your nested tables in the Data column will look like this:
[image]

Then you will just need to change your ExpandTable column step so that rather than referring to Column1, Column 2 etc it uses the actual column names

[image]